# Custom SessionListener, name is not bound in this context, javax.naming.NameNotFoundException

Tags: java, spring, servlets, dependency-injection, annotations

I am trying to implement HttpSessionListener so that users of this listener can register implementation of ISessionEvent interface to session Events.code is below:

```
public class MySessionListener implements HttpSessionListener{

 @Resource
 ISessionEvent sessionEvent;

 public ISessionEvent getSessionEvent() {
  return sessionEvent;
 }

 public void setSessionEvent(ISessionEvent sessionEvent) {
  this.sessionEvent = sessionEvent;
 }

 @Override
 public void sessionCreated(HttpSessionEvent arg0) {
  sessionEvent.SessionCreated(arg0.getSession());
 }

 @Override
 public void sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent arg0) {
  sessionEvent.SessionDestroyed(arg0.getSession());
 }
}
```

When user implement ISessionEvent and add as a bean, SessionCreated and SessionDestroyed functions of implementation will be called when these events occured. You can ask why dont you just write inside listeners methods, i dont i'm just trying.

When i try the code above i got the following error message:

```
javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name com.mehmet6parmak.sessionlistener.MySessionListener is not bound in this Context
 at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:770)
 at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:153)
 at org.apache.catalina.util.DefaultAnnotationProcessor.lookupFieldResource(DefaultAnnotationProcessor.java:278)
 at org.apache.catalina.util.DefaultAnnotationProcessor.processAnnotations(DefaultAnnotationProcessor.java:187)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4082)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4630)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:785)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:445)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:519)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:710)
 at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:581)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
 at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
 at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
```

Resource annotation causes the error but i could not resolve it.

Thanks All...

**Interface and Implementation**

```
@Resource
public interface ISessionEvent {
```

public void SessionCreated(HttpSession session);
 public void SessionDestroyed(HttpSession session);

}

```
@Resource
public class SessionEvent implements ISessionEvent {

 @Override
 public void SessionDestroyed(HttpSession session) {
  System.out.println("From Session Event Callback(Destroy):" + session.getId());
 }

 @Override
 public void SessionCreated(HttpSession session) {
  System.out.println("From Session Event Callback(Create):" + session.getId());
 }

}
```

**Bean Definition**

```
<context:annotation-config/>
<context:component-scan base-package="com.mehmet6parmak">
</context:component-scan>

<bean id="sessionEvent" autowire="byName" class="com.mehmet6parmak.sessionlistener.SessionEvent"></bean>
```

**Solution:**Using the method used in [link](http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-how-to-do-dependency-injection-in-your-session-listener/) works.

Comment: which version of tomcat you are using

Answer (score 1):

It's merely because `ISessionEvent` is not managed, I believe. Does it have `@Resource` annotation? Something like,

```
@Resource
public class ISessionEvent {...}
```

Comment: i added but still getting same error message, I've added interface, implementation and bean definition, if you ve got any other idea i'd appreciate thanks

Answer (score 0):

i have no experience about annotated listeners and Co. but, 
i checked the method on Specs, i met the following:

```
protected static void lookupFieldResource(javax.naming.Context context,
                                          java.lang.Object instance,
                                          java.lang.reflect.Field field,
                                          java.lang.String name,
                                          java.lang.Class<?> clazz)
                                   throws javax.naming.NamingException,
                                          java.lang.IllegalAccessException
```

Inject resources in specified field.
Throws:
javax.naming.NamingException
java.lang.IllegalAccessException

that means, you try to inject a resource into your field which must be a JNDI resource.

@Resource annotation works with a JNDI- entry:
http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/annotation/Resource.html

did you forget to define your resources in JNDI Context?

Update
Resource injection article:
http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2EE/injection/

Comment: i tried @Resource(name="com.mehmet6parmak.sessionlistener/MySessionListener") but nothing changed.

Comment: @mehmet6parmak: Why do you have a slash, instead of a period, before `MySessionListener`.